# What is "cast" means? I don't get it

Tags: meaning, nouns

For example,

> He said he can cook with casts on his arms.

In this sentence, what does "casts" mean?

Comment: https://www.medicinenet.com/cast/definition.htm#:~:text=Cast%3A%201)%20A%20protective%20shell,forms%20in%20a%20body%20cavity.
1) A protective shell of fiberglass, plastic, or plaster, and bandage that is molded to protect broken or fractured limb(s) as it heals.

Comment: I can see why this might have confused you, as my dictionary's entry for "cast" is very long with a lot of different possibilities.  Chess_lover's comment above has the correct and relevant one.  Now that that's been pointed out, I think we should close this question as being answerable with a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

A 'cast' on a limb or part of the body, sometimes 'plaster cast', is a cover, often made of plaster, which is used to protect a broken bone by keeping part of the body stiff.

[Plaster cast (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/plaster-cast)

[image]